# create an email digest using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've put together a script that automatically kicks out an email when a certain condition is met. This works well, sending out an email every time conditions are right; makes for a lot of emails though...

There are several blocks of code looking for different parameters, like this one:

```
//checking for 2 months from now
    if (
      expireDateMonth === twoMonthsMonth &&
      expireDateDay === twoMonthsDay &&
      expireDateYear === twoMonthsYear
    ) {
      var subject =
        'A license is expiring in 2 months: ' +
        row[x] + ' ' +
        expireDateFormat;
      MailApp.sendEmail('permissions@makethisworkplease.now', subject, message);
      Logger.log('2 months from now');
    }
```

Each of them sends out an email when triggered. What I'd like to do is make any triggers that pop, go out in ONE email digest at a time .  Appreciate any thoughts on this matter. Because of my work, I cannot use external services to accomplish this task.

Comment: What triggers you script to run?  If it's a simple trigger then it requires a user's input.  It will not fire on the actions of formulas or other scripts. No work around except for polling

Comment: You may be able to collect the messages in PropertiesService or in another file and then dump them at once a day with a time based trigger.  But I can't be sure since you have provide an [mcve]

Comment: @Cooper the script reads a sheet and when it lands on a certain date, it triggers an email notification. The dates vary and I can't figure out how to have all of them report out in one email; especially since the script is run at repeated intervals. What can I do to clarify my question, I am a tyro?

Comment: If this is the case you need to have the script read the whole sheet and accumulate the email content in a variable and then pass that variable content as message to the MailApp.sendEmail function once the whole sheet is read.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly my thinking. I'll try this suggestion as well as the PropertiesService solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are dead set in those intervals you set for your script to be triggered (assuming they are time-based), the idea below should be a viable option for you.

Storing the data in `PropertiesService` (as per Cooper's comment) is a good way of tackling the issue. Then every last interval of the day, you need to collate all those data into a single email.

#### Code

```
function sendBulkEmail() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var user = 'user@domain.com';
  // Condition and data here are just placeholders
  // Ran the script twice with different data
  var condition = true; 
  // First was John Doe, and next is John Reese
  var data1 = 'John Reese'; 
  var data2 = new Date();

  if (condition) {
    var message = data1 + ' ' + data2 + '\n';
    // if TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE already contains a data, it will be appended with the 
    // new data from the recent run
    message = scriptProperties.getProperty('TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE') + message;
    scriptProperties.setProperty('TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE', message); 
  }
  
  // If TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE has data and current run is triggered during 1 am 
  // Assuming your trigger is per n-hours and one trigger is timed at 1 am daily
  // Used 1am since it is my current time, but 11pm should be better for live data
  if(scriptProperties.getProperty('TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE') && new Date().getHours() == 1) {
    subject = 'A license is expiring in 2 months: ';
    // get all accumulated message for a certain condition and then dump in one email
    // if you have other conditions, you can append them all and have conditions 
    // to modify subject and message based on data availability
    message = scriptProperties.getProperty('TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE');
    MailApp.sendEmail(user, subject, message);

    // reset TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE value to blank after sending the data so it
    // won't be included in the email to be sent the next day.   
    scriptProperties.setProperty('TWOMONTHS_MESSAGE', ''); 
  }
}
```

#### Sample Output:

[image: sample output]

#### Reference:

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: Hi @Pers, thank you for checking my answer. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: hello, no accept button was shown. but answer is acceptable

Comment: Hi @Pers, that would be the check button on the left side of the answer.